# Using spring-kafka as configuration framework

Tags: spring-kafka

My question may sound weird, but still.
Is it possible to use `spring-kafka` only as a configuration framework - like parsing `application.properties` or `application.yaml` and instantiate consumer and producer without Spring Boot Autoconfiguration facilities? Basically, minimal sprinkles of `spring` and `spring-kafka` for just `public static void main` application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with a "configuration framework", but from your description it sounds like you still want to use `spring-kafka`. So, there is nothing wrong to have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to resolve `@Value` annotations for configuration properties against your `application.properties` in the `@PropertySource`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans

See sample in Spring for Apache Kafka docs how to configure `spring-kafka` without Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#with-java-configuration

So, you need to combine `spring-kafka` feature with that `@PropertySource` + `@Value` for parsing configuration properties.

Essentially you are going to do whatever Spring Boot does for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Artem! I appreciate your input.